# Use-package :bind-keymap with car as a form

Tags: use-package, syntax, error

As you can see below, trying to make a cons using a backquote and a colon to evaluate a form causes an error. Surely this is a tiny mistake, but Lisp is not my cup of tea.

Let's just jump to the code:

```lisp
(defconst ade/cmd-pfx-plain "C-SPC" "String for prefix of package prefixes.")

;; ...some time later...

(use-package projectile
  :config
  (projectile-mode)

  :bind-keymap

  ;; `(,(concat ade/cmd-pfx-plain " p") . projectile-command-map)
  ;; The above fails with:
  ;; "Error (use-package): Failed to parse package projectile: use-package:
  ;; projectile wants arguments acceptable to the `bind-keys'
  ;; macro, or a list of such values"

  ;; So far I'm forced to do this instead:
  ("C-SPC p" . projectile-command-map))
```

((If you're feeling adventurous and want to see my *actual* config, [here it is](https://github.com/AnthonyD973/ademacs/blob/0789a2890c45d727ba6f0a8394f1e0f9bb8f826b/ademacs.d/init.el#L532).))

Comment: What happens if you remove both the backquote and the comma?

Comment: Then I get `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "use-package: projectile wants arguments acceptable to the 'bind-keys' macro, or a list of such values")`

Comment: I've added a link to my actual config in the OP, but feel free to ask me to change the OP's example if needed.

Comment: The issue here is use-package is a macro (https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Macros.html), which "operate on the unevaluated expressions for the arguments, not on the argument values as functions do".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you are seeing is because `use-package` is a [macro](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Macros.html) rather than a function. As noted in the manual, macros "operate on the unevaluated expressions for the arguments".

You can see what lisp a macro expands to by putting point at the end and calling `pp-macroexpand-last-sexp`. If you do this on your working example you will see that it includes this to bind your keymap:

```
(bind-key "C-SPC p"
              #'(lambda nil
                  (interactive)
                  (use-package-autoload-keymap 'projectile-command-map 'projectile nil)))
```

One option to do what you want is to do this yourself in an `:init`, for example:

```
(use-package projectile
  :config
  (projectile-mode)

  :init
  (let ((prefix (concat ade/cmd-pfx-plain " p")))
    (bind-key prefix
              #'(lambda nil
                  (interactive)
                  (use-package-autoload-keymap 'projectile-command-map 'projectile nil)))))
```

Comment: Yes, [it works!](https://github.com/AnthonyD973/ademacs/commit/d52cb8ad37b632d52d62db60ab1157df4f937729) Thank you.